# Where can I find the ARPCOMMENTS through the Visual Studio GUI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project

Where can I find the [ARPCOMMENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367585(VS.85,printer).aspx) through the Visual Studio GUI in a .NET solution with a setup project?

The value of ARPCOMMENTS shows up when "Click here for
support information." is clicked in Control Panel "Add or
Remove Programs". I have changed it once, but I forgot where
it is.

Comment: "...but I forgot where it is" happens to me all the time. +1 for honesty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is confusing that the immediately apparent *Properties* from
the context menu for a setup project will open a window with
***configuration*** options.

Whereas selecting the setup project and pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> (or menu
*View* → *Properties Window*) will open the desired
window where property Description can be edited:

[image: Screenshot of the property window for a Visual Studio setup project]

(ARPCOMMENTS is the same as property Description - it is
stored in the project file for the setup project,
MascotParserSetup.vdproj in my case.)

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Why do they hide this away the Properties inside an obscure keypress?

Answer (score 2):

From:

[Setup project - Deployment project properties - using [ProductVersion] inside Description property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/34998fdc-e985-4339-b475-03be69eecaa5)

> The Description property of the setup
>   project stands for the MSI standard
>   property ARPCOMMENTS. If we set the
>   value of the Description property of a
>   setup project, an item will be added
>   to the Properties table in the
>   resulted MSI package to set the value
>   of the ARPCOMMENTS property.
>
> The remarks part of the MSDN document
>   about Property table mentions:
>
> "You cannot use the Property table to
>   set a property to the value of another
>   property. The installer does nothing
>   to the text string entered in the
>   Value column before setting the
>   property in the Property column."
>
> "This is necessary to prevent creating
>   circular references in the Property
>   table. Instead, you can set one
>   property to another by using a Custom
>   Action Type 51."
>
> So the solution of your problem is to
>   add a type 51 custom action to the MSI
>   package. Unfortunately, Visual Studio
>   doesn't support adding a type 51
>   custom action in the setup project. I
>   suggest that you do this using Orca.
>
> The following are the steps to add a
>   type 51 custom action to an MSI
>   package:
>   1. Build your setup project in Visual Studio.
>   2. Open the resulted MSI package with Orca.
>   3. Locate the CustomAction table in the left list and add a new row in
>   this table as follows:
>       Action                          Type          Source
>   Target
>       Set_ARPCOMMENTS       51             ARPCOMMENTS         ... version
>   [ProductVersion] ...
>   4. Locate the InstallExecuteSequence table and add a new row to call the
>   above custom action. You can sequence
>   the call to the custom action after
>   the DIRCA_TARGETDIR action. For
>   example:
>       Action                            Condition                    Sequence
>       Set_ARPCOMMENTS         NOT Installed                 760
>   5. Save the changes.
>   6. Install the modified MSI package on the target machine.
>
> Hope this helps. If you have any
>   question, please feel free to let me
>   know.
>
> Sincerely, Linda Liu